# using (windows) PowerShell to perform a dynamic DNS update with TSIG to a BIND9 server

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, bind, dynamic-dns, ddns

I run BIND9 DNS servers and allow Dynamic DNS updates from my customers by using a TSIG key.

One of my customers uses only a Windows environment, and therefore PowerShell to run scripts. He wants to use PowerShell to send dynamic updates to my servers.

Doing this from a Linux shell for testing is easy: use nsupdate.

from: https://www.freeipa.org/page/Howto/DNS_updates_and_zone_transfers_with_TSIG

> Client
>
> For nsupdate from bind-utils package you have to either use
>   option -y algorithm:keyname:keyvalue or -k keyfilename option. E.g.
>
> `$ nsupdate -y hmac-sha512:keyname:keyvalue`
>
> or
>
> `$ nsupdate -k Kkeyname.+165+0316.private`

then do your update:

from https://linux.die.net/man/8/nsupdate:

> ```
> # nsupdate
> > update delete oldhost.example.com A
> > update add newhost.example.com 86400 A 172.16.1.1
> > send
> ```

To do an update from Powershell **without** TSIG is ... kinda easy... I think?: use a cmdlet (for example) [Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/add-dnsserverresourcerecorda?view=win10-ps)

> ```
> Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name "host23" -ZoneName "contoso.com" - AllowUpdateAny -IPv4Address "172.18.99.23" -TimeToLive 01:00:00
> ```

After scouring the documentation, I don't see any references to Transaction Signatures or somehow using a TSIG key.

**How do I send a dynamic update using a TISG key to a BIND9 server from Powershell?**

This is frustratingly hard to find an example of. Most examples I can find are using PowerShell to send updates via an API which then (probably) does some kind of deploy or dynamic update inside a black box. I want to just build a DDNS update and send it off using PowerShell.

Comment: There are several programming languages (other then powershell) that support it (eg python w/dnspython). You could also use nsupdate from WSL.

Comment: I have created a powershell script last night that does exactly what you are looking for. I will be answering with the first version of the script later tonight when I can get back to my lab network.
1. get interfaces, dns servers and connection specific DNS domains. 2. digest the output for processing 4. tests if records match existing DNS on connection DNS servers 3. generate an nsupdate script file which deletes the record and creates A and AAAA records as well as PTR records 5. saves to a temp file and calls nsupdate.exe with the script file

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question... The problem is that nsupdate isn't in Powershell. I am looking for the Microsoft comparable product, usable in Powershell. It appears not to exist. Unless your script constructs packets like nsupdate does, it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

They will have to download nsupdate from BIND (https://www.isc.org/downloads/).  It is possible to call nsupdate from a PowerShell host.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a script that will create and submit DDNS requests if a tsig file is provided. Ensure NTFS permissions are set to prevent unauthorized users (including other admins) from accessing this file.

This does assume that you have installed nsupdate.exe and the associated dll's in C:\windows\system32 but it can be modified for other paths.

I welcome any pull requests.
https://github.com/ACiDGRiM/UsefulScripts/blob/master/Update-DNS.ps1

```
Param (
    [String]$KeyPath = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\windows-update-client.txt",
    [String]$NSScriptPath = "$env:Temp\nsupdate.txt",
    [String]$NSUpdatePath = "$env:SystemRoot\System32"
)

begin {
    #Gather status of system IP Addresses, DNS Servers, and domains
    $IPAddresses = Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.InterfaceAlias -like "Ethernet*" -or $_.InterfaceAlias -like "Wi-Fi*") -and $_.IPAddress -notlike "fe*"}
    $DNSServers = Get-DnsClientServerAddress | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.InterfaceAlias -like "Ethernet*" -or $_.InterfaceAlias -like "Wi-Fi*"}
    $DNSClient = Get-DnsClient | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.InterfaceAlias -like "Ethernet*" -or $_.InterfaceAlias -like "Wi-Fi*"}
}

process {
    [array]$RequestOutput = @()
    #Parse network status into simplified objects
    foreach ( $if in $IPAddresses ) {
        $requesthash = @{
            IPAddress = @{Address = $if.IPAddress;AddressFamily = $if.AddressFamily}
            Zone = $DNSClient | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.InterfaceAlias -eq $if.InterfaceAlias } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "ConnectionSpecificSuffix" -First 1
            Servers = $DnsServers | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.InterfaceAlias -eq $if.InterfaceAlias } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "ServerAddresses"
        }
        $RequestObj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $requesthash
        $RequestOutput += $RequestObj 

    }

    #Condense zones from multiple interfaces
    [array]$UniqueZones = ($RequestOutput.Zone|Sort-Object -Unique)
    #Combine IPv6 and IPv4 addresses into a single object property for each zone
    [array]$CombinedOutput = @()
    for ($i=0;$i -lt $UniqueZones.count;$i++) {
        $Combinedhash = @{
            Addresses = $RequestOutput | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Zone -eq $UniqueZones[$i]} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "IPAddress"
            Servers = $RequestOutput | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Zone -eq $UniqueZones[$i]} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Servers" | Sort-Object -Unique
            Zone = $UniqueZones[$i]
        }
        $CombinedObj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Combinedhash
        $CombinedOutput += $CombinedObj 
    }

    foreach ( $o in $CombinedOutput ) {
        foreach ( $s in $o.Servers ) {
            $CurrentRecords = Resolve-DnsName $env:COMPUTERNAME`.$($o.Zone) -Server $s -Type "A_AAAA" -DnsOnly -DnssecOK -QuickTimeout -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "IPAddress" -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
            if ( $CurrentRecords ) {
                $CurrentState = Compare-Object $IPAddresses.IPAddress $CurrentRecords -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
            } else {
                $CurrentState = $true
            }

            if ( $CurrentState ) {
                $script += "server $s
"
                foreach ( $a in $o.Addresses ) {
                    if ( $a.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4" ) {
                        $PTR = $a.Address -replace '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.\d+\.(\d+)$','$3.$2.$1.in-addr.arpa.'
                    } else {
                        $PTR = (([char[]][BitConverter]::ToString(([IPAddress]$a.Address).GetAddressBytes())-ne'-')[31..0]-join".")+'.ip6.arpa.'
                    }
                    $script += "update delete $env:COMPUTERNAME.$($o.Zone). $(if($a.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"){"A"}else{"AAAA"})

update add $env:COMPUTERNAME.$($o.Zone). 60 $(if($a.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"){"A"}else{"AAAA"}) $($a.Address)

update delete $PTR PTR

update add $PTR 60 PTR $env:COMPUTERNAME.$($o.Zone).


"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

end {
    $script | Out-File -FilePath $NSScriptPath -Encoding "ascii" -Force
    Start-Process -FilePath (Join-Path -Path $NSUpdatePath -ChildPath "nsupdate.exe") -ArgumentList "-d -k `"$KeyPath`" `"$NSScriptPath`"" -Wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError "$env:TEMP\nsstderr" -RedirectStandardOutput "$env:TEMP\nsstdout" -WorkingDirectory $NSUpdatePath | Out-Null

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question... The problem is that nsupdate isn't in Powershell. I am looking for the Microsoft comparable product, usable in Powershell. It appears not to exist. Unless your script constructs packets like nsupdate does, it does not answer my question... and it appears to *rely on* nsupdate being installed - missing the point.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for those Who don't have Static IP Address and Need to Update IP Dynamically for DNS zone and reverse DNS PTR records too

```
            $Server = "your server"; $Hostname = "mail"; $Zonename = "your zone"; 
            $MZone = $Hostname + "." + $Zonename
            <# No need to edit below unless you have to change some internal component #>

            $oldobj = get-dnsserverresourcerecord -ComputerName $Server -name $Hostname -zonename $zonename -rrtype "A"
            $newobj = get-dnsserverresourcerecord -ComputerName $Server -name $Hostname -zonename $zonename -rrtype "A"
            $ip =  (Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).Content.Trim()   
            $oip = $oldobj.recorddata.Ipv4address.IpAddressToString
            $oipSplit = $oip.Split("."); $oipr = $oipSplit[2] + "." + $oipSplit[1] + "." + $oipSplit[0] + ".in-addr.arpa"
            $ipSplit = $ip.Split("."); $ipr = $ipSplit[2] + "." + $ipSplit[1] + "." + $ipSplit[0] + ".in-addr.arpa"
            $newobj.recorddata.ipv4address=[System.Net.IPAddress]::parse($ip)
            if ($oip -ne $ip) {
                Set-dnsserverresourcerecord -ComputerName $Server -newinputobject $newobj -oldinputobject $oldobj -zonename $zonename -passthru
                echo "updated A record"
            }
            $oiprZ = Resolve-DnsName -Name $oipr -Server $Server; $oiprR = 0;
            if ($oiprZ.count -gt 0) {
                $oiprR = get-dnsserverresourcerecord -ComputerName $Server -ZoneName $oipr -rrtype "PTR"  -Name $oipSplit[3] | Select-Object HostName, @{Name='RecordData';Expression={$MZone}} 
                if ($oiprR -ne 0 -And $oiprR -ne $null -and -not ($oiprR[0].HostName -eq $ipSplit[3] -and $oiprR[0].RecordData -eq $MZone -and  $oipr -eq $ipr )  ){
                    Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $Server -ZoneName $oipr -rrtype "PTR" -Name $oipSplit[3] -RecordData $MZone -Force
                    echo "removing existing ptr record"
                    echo $oiprR
                    echo "removed existing ptr record"
                }
                $oiprR =get-dnsserverresourcerecord -ComputerName $Server -ZoneName $oipr -rrtype "PTR"
                if (((($oiprR) -eq $null) -or (($oiprR).Count  -eq 0)) -And $oipr -ne $ipr )  {
                    Remove-DnsServerZone  -ComputerName $Server $oipr -PassThru -Verbose -Force
                    echo "Removing RDNS Zone"
                    echo $oiprZ
                    echo "Removing RDNS Zone"

                }
            }


            $ipNID = $ipSplit[0] + "." + $ipSplit[1] + "." + $ipSplit[2] + ".0/24"
            $iprZ = Resolve-DnsName -Name $ipr -Server $Server; $iprR = 0;
            if ($iprZ.count -gt 0) {
                $iprR = get-dnsserverresourcerecord -ComputerName $Server -ZoneName $ipr -rrtype "PTR"  -Name $ipSplit[3] | Select-Object HostName, @{Name='RecordData';Expression={$MZone}} 
                if ($iprR -eq $null ){
                Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr  -ComputerName $Server  -Name $ipSplit[3] -ZoneName $ipr -AllowUpdateAny -TimeToLive 01:00:00 -AgeRecord -PtrDomainName $MZone
                    echo "adding ptr record"
                    echo $iprR
                    echo "added ptr record"
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            if ($iprZ.count -eq 0) {
                Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone  -ComputerName $Server -DynamicUpdate Secure -NetworkId $ipNID -ReplicationScope Domain
                Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr  -ComputerName $Server  -Name $ipSplit[3] -ZoneName $ipr -AllowUpdateAny -TimeToLive 01:00:00 -AgeRecord -PtrDomainName $MZone
            }
```